# iMac with Linux Dual Boot... change second hard drive permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, mac, permissions

Just finished a successful dual-boot process of macOS and Ubuntu 16.04 on my iMac.  My computer has an SSD which houses the two partitions and OS's and a 1TB HDD with all the data from my Mac work (named Macintosh HD 2).

I can read and access Mac HD 2, but I can't write to it (no surprise). When I look at the properties and permissions tab on the drive, it says that `root` is the owner, `80` is the group, and nothing under "Others".

Using nano as `root` to write a test doc to the drive doesn't work.

I'd like to be careful with `chmod` or `chown` before I possibly open up the drive to security holes... Should I do that? What the best option?

**Edit:** Running the command

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/group
```

reveals no such group named `80`.  I tried to use `adduser` to add my username to the group, but it claims no 80 group exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Success!**

Ok, so I finally got it to work, but it was a much simpler solution than I expected.

Essentially, all you have to do is turn off drive ownership to the desired volume. My Mac has two drives: one SSD for the OS (Mac HD) and an HDD (Mac HD 2) for data.

First, boot into Mac OS.  Right click on the data drive (Mac HD 2) and get info.  Unlock the lock icon and then click the check box that's labeled "Ignore ownership on this volume".

Apply to all the contents of the drive.

**IMPORTANT:**

**DO NOT** do this to the OS drive or any drive which you use to boot! Only do this to a data storage device (interior one, that is) that you want to share.

[More information here.](https://larryjordan.com/articles/mac-os-set-hard-drive-permissions/)

**SIDE NOTE:** Anyone who wants to try this, may or may not experience some trouble if the volume is formatted with Mac OS Extended with journaling.  I disabled journaling on mine before I found this solution, so I don't know if that helped or not.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a sub-directory off "Mac HD 2" called `Users/<username>` or `Work/<username>` or whatever you'd prefer and `chown it to your username.  This way the main disk is still owned by root and you can add additional folders off that base for whatever purpose. If you'd prefer to run your Mac home directory there, go the Users route, copy your existing home directory contents into the new one and then change your home directory within System Preferences -> Users & Groups (right-click to get Advanced Options which contains the path to your home directory.

Given you're running Ubuntu and working in the Mac Terminal, I assume you can figure out the correct commands. Just don't forgot to use `sudo` when you first create the new folder and `chown` it.